# "If checked, this work item is being tracked for KPI measurements"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Curious about this tab on work items in Azure Devops.

I assume this is for administrators/managers to track how fast things get done? Can you sort by Assignee and tell how fast or delayed individuals make progress?

[image: Tracking Feature]

[image: Tracking tab]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, the Tracking tab may be a [custom page in your project process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-form?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-page) and the Tracking function seems like an [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/overview?view=azure-devops) installed in your organization. By default, there's no Tracking tab in the work item layout.

Therefore, not sure if the tracking function you are using can sort by Assignee and tell how fast or delayed individuals make progress since it's not a built-in feature in Azure DevOps. You can confirm with your admin or try to contact the team who published the extension for more details.

However, there's built-in feature in Azure DevOps that may meet your requirement to sort by Assignee and tell how fast or delayed individuals make progress. You can set sprint capacity to help you track each assignee's work progress.

First you need to set capacity for the team and team members in Sprint->Capacity.
[image]

As you define tasks and estimate the work, you'll see capacity charts start to fill in for each team member. Capacity bars track the remaining work against the capacity for each team member and the entire team.

[image]

From this view, you can easily see which individuals are at or near capacity. Teams can determine if work needs to be moved out of the sprint or to reassign tasks.

For your reference, you can find more details in the official doc: [Determine and set sprint capacity in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops). Hope it helps.

Comment: If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for your warm reply. :-)